# Node.js: Running a script as file or interactive produces different result

Tags: node.js

if I save the lines below and run like ./node saved.js

```
var that = this;
that.val1 = 109;
var f1 = function(){return this;}
var f2 = function(){return this;}
var that1 = f1();
var that2 = f2();
console.log(that1.val1)//undefined
that1.val2=111;
console.log(that2.val2)//111
```

I get this result

```
undefined
111
```

But if I paste it to already started shell ./node, I get

```
...
...
> console.log(that1.val1)//undefined
109
undefined
> that1.val2=111;
111
> console.log(that2.val2)//111
111
```

Why is the output of the first console.log different?

Comment: The REPL (interactive mode) executes code in the global scope where `this === global` while Module files are [run in their own scope](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) where `this === module.exports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it in the script, `this` inside of your functions refers to a different object than it does outside your functions.  For example, I made this change to the beginning of your script:

```
var that = this;
console.log(this)
that.val1 = 109;
var f1 = function(){console.log(this); console.log("eq: " + (this === that));return this;}
```

When that second line executes running it as `node test.js`, I get an empty object, whereas then the one inside of `f1` is executed a few lines deeper, it's a much different object.

When that's run from the Node REPL, I get an object matching the one from inside `f1` in the `node test.js` version in both places.  Thus, `that.va1 = 109` is acting on different objects in the 2 cases and is why you see the difference.

Edit: And see Jonathan Lonowski's comment on the question for what the 2 different objects are.